# matlab 4D interpolation plot

Tags: matlab, plot, interpolation, 4d

Here is a sample dataset.

```
x = linspace(10,20,50);
y = linspace(10,20,50);
z = cos(linspace(0,2*pi,50));
time = linspace(1,60,50);
sci_temp = randi(100,50,1);
```

x,y,z is position, and sci_temp is temperature data.

I wonder how to draw trajectory over xyz position with sci_temp data.

I try interpolate data, so I get 2D interpolate time vs z with sci_temp plot.

```
S = TriScatteredInterp(time',z',sci_temp);
[t_mesh z_mesh] = meshgrid(time,z);
tz_mesh = S(t_mesh, z_mesh);
pcolor(t_mesh,z_mesh,tz_mesh)
```

[image: result]

What I want to get is a 2D (time vs sci_temp) section map on a xyz 3D plot. Like this image.

[image: result]

how to show trajectory over sci_temp in 3D plot?

Is there anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are doing your interpolation slightly wrong, you don't want to interpolate over the mesh created by

```
meshgrid(time,z);
```

Because it will duplicate values. You want to interpolate over the mesh created by

```
meshgrid(time,linspace(min(z),max(z),50));
```

Once you get the interpolated values like:
[image]
You can plot them in 3D space with the `surface` function, you just need to make sure to give x and y coordinates appropriately

```
surface(repmat(x,50,1),repmat(y,50,1),zmesh,tzmesh)
```

[image]

You can even have more complex paths, for example, same data but `y=z`

[image]

---

Edit: Also I forgot to mention, I'd suggest you to use `scatteredInterpolant` instead of `TriScatteredInterp`. It gives you more control over the interpolation

Comment: I wonder how to correspond the each time and each location one to one.

Comment: I solve that, >> [x_mesh t_mesh] = meshgrid(x,time); [y_mesh t_mesh] = meshgrid(y,time); [t_mesh z_mesh] = meshgrid(time,linspace(min(z),max(z),50) surf(x_mesh,y_mesh,t_mesh,zt_mesh) THANKS A LOT!!!!